# Python filter data frame with string pattern in function

Tags: python, string

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to write a function to filter a data frame using a search, which will be applied in an app. I want to search a string for a specific pattern in the beginning of the string.

At the moment, I have successfully achieved this, but only for string containing the pattern, anywhere in the string. This is my code:

```
sequence = [["TTTGCGAAA", "ref"], ["TTTGGGAAA", "ref"], ["TTGGGGTTT", "iso"], ["TTAGGGAAA", "iso"], ["TATGGGAAA", "iso"]]  
df = pd.DataFrame(sequence, columns=["sequence", "mapping"])  

def search_table(search):  
    filtered_df = df[df['sequence'].str.contains(search)]
    print(filtered_df)

search_table("TTT")
```

```
output:
    sequence mapping
0  TTTGCGAAA     ref
1  TTTGGGAAA     ref
2  TTGGGGTTT     iso
```

But this^ is not exactly what I want. My desired output is below:

```
    sequence mapping
0  TTTGCGAAA     ref
1  TTTGGGAAA     ref
```

I have looked at reg express but I have not at all been successful. Can someone please help me or suggest what functions I could try?

Comment: try to use `.startswith()` instead of `.contains()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add  `^` on str.contains method

```py
    def search_table(search):  
        filtered_df = df[df['sequence'].str.contains('^'+search)]
        print(filtered_df)
```

This is a regex symbol for begin of a line. By default, `str.contains` accepts regex.

It is worth studying manuals and tutorials about regex because it helps a lot in many cases like this or even in other languages.

Another possibility for your problem would be to use:

```py
    df[df.sequence.str.contains('^('+yourpattern+'){'+N+'}')]
```

Where `^` means  begin of line and `('yourpattern'){N}` means 'yourpattern' N times with yourpattern a string and N an integer

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.contains` with the parameter `regex=True` and search for lines that contain your pattern.

```
df[df.sequence.str.contains(r'^T{3}', regex=True)]
```

The regex `^T{3}`  looks for a string that starts with `TTT`.

Comment: this did not work. the string pattern changes according to user input, so the pattern should not be specified in the function.